# Аппаратный генератор случайных чисел на процессоре

Tags: ассемблер, случайные-числа, процессор

Вопрос: а нет ли в современных процессорах CISC аппаратного ГСЧ? А если есть, то как с ним работать?

Вопрос просто для удовлетворения любопытства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в Википедии упоминание о [RdRand](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand). Процитирую здесь статью

RdRand это инструкция для генерации случайного числа при помощи встроенного генератора случайных чисел. RdRand доступен для архитектуры процессоров Ivy Bridge и является опциональным расширением набора инструкций Intel 64 и IA-32. Данный генератор случайных чисел соответствует стандартам безопасности и криптографическим стандартам, таким как NIST SP800-90, FIPS 140-2, и ANSI X9.82.

#### Описание

Для проверки поддержки процессором `RDRAND` можно использовать инструкцию `CPUID`. При наличии поддержки бит 30 регистра `ECX` оказывается установлен после вызова функции 01H инструкции CPUID. Опкод RDRAND `0x0F 0xC7`.

Компилятор С++, входящий в MS Visual Studio 2013, поддерживает RDRAND посредством функций `_rdrand16_step(unsigned short *random_val)` и `_rdrand32_step(unsigned int *random_val)`. Если удалось сгенерировать случайное число, используя аппаратный генератор процессора, функция возвращает 1, в противном случае возвращается 0. Само сгенерированное случайное число передается в память по указателю.

#### Алгоритм

Две пары чисел по 256 бит, полученных из аппаратного источника энтропии, передаются в аппаратный блок, выполняющий криптографический алгоритм AES в режиме CBC-MAC. Полученное 256-битное значение используется для инициализации ГПСЧ (CTR_DRBG из раздела 10.2.1 стандарта NIST SP 800-90, с использованием AES)